# How do I make my player object move in the direction it is facing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is what I have at the moment, but I can't find any solution for the gameobject moving in the direction it is facing.

```cs
private float vertical;
private float spinning;
private float spinningValue;
[SerializeField] private float spinningSpeed;
[SerializeField] private float speed;
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D playerRB;

private void Update()
{
    spinningValue += spinning* spinningSpeed;
    playerRB.velocity = new Vector3(0, vertical * speed);
    playerRB.SetRotation(spinningValue);
}

public void Move(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    vertical = context.ReadValue<Vector3>().y;
}
        
public void Spin(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    spinning = context.ReadValue<Vector3>().y;
}
```

I've tried using quaternions and vector.up, but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Not sure about that, but I would try to get the rotation and multiply it by Vector3.Forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
playerRB.velocity = new Vector3(0, vertical * speed);
```

makes your object move in global worldspace Y-axis direction.

Instead simply use e.g.

```
playerRB.velocity = (Vector2)(transform.up * vertical * speed);
```

which is then based on the current orientation

probably want to do this **after**

```
playerRB.SetRotation(spinningValue);
```

---

In general you should use `FixedUpdate` for anything physics related and not mix in anything via `Transform` at all. So probably something like e.g.

```
private Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.identity;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, spinning * spinningSpeed);

    playerRB.MoveRotation(rotation);
    playerRB.velocity = (Vector2)(rotation * Vector3.up * vertical * speed);
}
```

Comment: thank you good sir it worked, [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLkfz10Srxw) a appreciation gift